# Selecting nearest lat/lon in a netcdf that have lat/lon as variables

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file with the following characteristics:
[image]

I want to extract values from the variable "sd_days" based on latitude and longitude. I used the following code:

```
extract = data["sd_days"].sel(LON = 9.45, LAT 34.34, method = "nearest")
```

The code does not run because the latitude et longitude are not coordinates/dimensions of the variable "sd_days" but instead are standalone variables themselves. Using xarray (or another library), is there a way to edit the netcdf so that the "sd_days" have LON et LAT as coordinates/dimensions. To look something like: sd_days (time, LAT, LON).

I tried using xarray.merge or xarray.auto_combine but they do not give me the desired result.

I am using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10

Comment: You will need to provide more details. To convert the Lon/lat to coordinates properly you need to know what type of grid you are dealing with. Can you add that to the question.?

Answer (score 0):

Try if `data.sel(dict(LAT=34.34,LON=9.45),method="nearest").sd_days` works. Find the location first and then extract the data.